# Deciding on the type of scipy.sparse matrices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Suppose I need to perform the computations

```
A.dot(B).dot(A.T)
A.dot(x)
```

where `A` and `B` are both `scipy.sparse` matrices and `x` is a dense `np.array`. How should I decide on the type of sparse matrices to use for `A` and `B`? I know that `csc_matrix` is better for column-operations and `csr_matrix` is better for row-operations, so it seems that I should use `csr_matrix` for `A`, but I'm not sure what to do with `B` since I need to perform both row- and column- operations. Should I just store it as `coo_matrix` instead?

Comment: I don't think it matters, especially when matrix multiplication is the main operation.  Transpose of a `csr` is a `csc` (try it and look at the attributes).  `coo` is mainly an input format.  Any math will require conversion to a condensed format, usually automatically.

Comment: With many rows and few columns a `csc` `intptr` is smaller.  Conversely for `csr`.

Comment: It's a good idea to do some of your own time tests.  The latest scipy release talks about some speed improvements, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.1.0.0.html#scipy-sparse-improvements, which may, or not, affect your processing